# Associates the same model twice in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have two class `Intern::Question` and `Intern::Answer`, and the standard association look like :

```
class Intern::Question
  has_many :intern_answers, class_name: 'Intern::Answer'
end

class Intern::Answer
  belongs_to :intern_question, class_name: 'Intern::Question'
end
```

And now I want to reference twice answer belongs_to question, answer can store parent question and next question, something like :

```
class Intern::Question
  has_many :intern_answers, class_name: 'Intern::Answer'
  has_many :node_for_answers, class_name: 'Intern::Answer'
end

class Intern::Answer
  belongs_to :intern_question, foreign_key: :intern_question_id, class_name: 'Intern::Question'
  belongs_to :next_question, foreign_key: :next_question_id, class_name: 'Intern::Question'
end
```

But I have try that and get this error :

```
Mongoid::Errors::AmbiguousRelationship
```

Comment: @muistooshort sorry typo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16846849/1297435), using `inverse_of`

```
class Intern::Question
  has_many :intern_answers, class_name: 'Intern::Answer', inverse_of: :intern_question
  has_many :node_for_answers, class_name: 'Intern::Answer', inverse_of: :next_question
end

class Intern::Answer
  belongs_to :intern_question, foreign_key: :intern_question_id, class_name: 'Intern::Question', inverse_of: :intern_answers
  belongs_to :next_question, foreign_key: :next_question_id, class_name: 'Intern::Question', inverse_of: :node_for_answers
end
```